# Value of button as a 2-word variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked it up, but haven't found anything about two-word variables. I'm trying to set a button value as a variable, a name, that is two words. I've tried two different ways, but both end up only printing the first name, and not both.

```
var $div = $("<div></div>");
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    $div.append(
            "<p>"
            + "<input type='submit' value="+people[i].name+" id="+i+">"
            + "</p>"
            + "<br>"
    );
}
$("#left2").append($div);
```

and I've also tried this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        $("#left2").append(
            "<p>"
            + "<input type='submit' value="+people[i].name+" id="+i+">"
            + "</p>"
            + "<br>"
        );
    }
```

Why is it only printing out the first name, and not both?

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone! Wish I could accept all the answers, but you all got an upvote. I appreciate taking you taking the time to answer this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the value in quotes.Try this:

```
"<input type='submit' value='"+people[i].name+"' id='"+i+"'>"
```

Ideally, any attribute value must be in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

`value` should be in single quotes in this case

```
+ "<input type='submit' value='"+people[i].name+"' id="+i+">"
```

---

This will produce HTML:

```
<input type='submit' value='My Name' id=1>
```

Your code produced code like:

```
<input type='submit' value=My Name id=1>
```

So `value` was just `"My"` and also some separate attribute `Name`

To avoid this errors in future *always* wrap attribute values in quotes

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        $("#left2").append(
            "<p>"
            + "<input type='submit' value='"+people[i].name+"' id="+i+">"
            + "</p>"
            + "<br>"
        );
    }
```

This way the single quotes will indicate the start and finisch of the attribute value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    $("#left2").append(
        "<p>"
        + "<input type='submit' value='"+people[i].name+"' id="+i+">"
        + "</p>"
        + "<br>"
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.
important point is that the value should be inside the single quates.

```
 "<input type='submit' value='"+people[i].name+"' id="+i+">"
```